# Fusion by collision?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics

So, I'm still working on the plasma weaponry, the shape is a:

**Spheromak:** The spheromak is a type of plasma configuration which enables the plasma to contain itself with its own magnetic field, even when external fields aren't present. Plasma's shape with this configuration resembles that of a smoke ring. Another notable trait is that its stability increases with its temperature.

The fairing is under development, but there's another problem:

**Is it possible to trigger fusion in a spheromak nitrogen plasma by colliding it with a (and only with a) solid object at high speeds?**

Comment: I don't have any kind of numbers to provide you, but you would have to slam the molecules into the target at speeds which the target cannot bend/move out of the way. Probably talking fractions of the speed of light. So, yes, you can trigger fusion by collision, but I feel you would still have a deadly weapon far before you hit that velocity.

Comment: While not super sciency read [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/), for a description of how a collision of a hard body with air (so mostly nitrogen) can make plasma

Comment: I would say no. Effects of fusion in the case will be minuscule. I recomend to watch that video about fusion - [MIT's Pathway to Fusion Energy (IAP 2017) - Zach Hartwig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0KuAx1COEk) It may help you with better understanding of the process.

Answer (score 5):

Triggering fusion by collision has been studied for a long time, and certain schemes have been proposed, but generally fail due to the enormous energies needed to trigger fusion in nuclear materials like D2 or 3He. A good primer can be found [here](https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2016/06/gun-fusion-two-barrels-to-stars.html)

Creating an energetic plasma in nitrogen might not be as challenging, but holding the plasma together when it is created by two masses slamming into each other at hundreds of *kilometres per second* will be very challenging, to say the least.

This also raises another point. A 64 MJ railgun is proposed as a weapon for the US Navy, but requires an entire ship to provide the power and ancillary systems to be a usable weapon. The energy thought to be needed for gun fusion is 160 MJ, so the system will be even larger and less portable.

If you *really* want to fire high energy plasma at people, consider a nuclear powered [CASABA Howitzer](https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2016/06/the-nuclear-spear-casaba-howitzer.html), which can fire star hot plasma at 10% of the speed of light, and theoretically would take out an aircraft carrier if fired from LEO. Aim off and other factors become less important with that sort of firepower......

Answer (score 2):

Nitrogen cycle ignites at ~15×10<sup>6</sup> K (see: [CNO Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle)) which is a bit high to achieve via solid body collision.

I would say there's no way you can get that temperature unless you have a "plasma bullet" traveling at a sizable fraction of the speed of light.

In such condition your plasma would probably start nuclear reactions in anything along its trajectory, well before reaching its solid target. Plasma would be several order of magnitude cooler than required, so many, in fact it wouldn't matter if it is plasma or "normal" matter.

Comment: From earlier posts, I think he means that the plasma bubble is moving and the solid object is a wall or target.  So yiur use of *bullet* will confuse him.

Comment: For temperatures expressed on the Kelvin scale, we do not use the degree (°) symbol. It's "some number of Kelvin", not "some number of degrees Kelvin". Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin.

Comment: The CNO cycle is nitrogen + hydrogen, not nitrogen + nitrogen.  How much hydrogen will it hit?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon Arvex's comment, lets look at the energy levels involved.

Lets look at your nitrogen plasma.

Kinetic energy = 3/2 * [Boltzmann's constant] * temperature.

Lets figure that ZioByte is right about the process being the CNO cycle (something I have my doubts about) and thus our temperature has a minimum value of 15E+6 K.  (And to get a lot of fusion energy you'll need a temperature **far** above this!)

1.5 * 1.38E-23 * 1.5E+7 = 3.105E-16 J/molecule.
6.242e+18 eV/J = 2.01E+2 eV.

Supposing one of those nitrogen atoms hits a hydrogen atom and fuses we get 7.35 MeV.

For the fusion energy to match the kinetic energy we thus need at least 1 
atom in 36 thousand to actually fuse with the target.  If fusion actually proceeded at that rate at 1.5E+7 degrees we would have an explosion in the sky, not a sun.  (And note that you picked exactly the wrong gas, the N14 + H1 is the slowest step of the CNO cycle!)

The nitrogen is only moving on the order of 30km/sec to accomplish this.

However, I find these numbers suspect.  The problem is saying the CNO cycle starts at 1.5E+7 degrees sort of implies both atoms are moving at that temperature, I think we need to double it to actually get fusion.  If I'm correct in this we must double the kinetic energy, thus changing it to 1 atom in 18 thousand and speeding our nitrogen up to a bit over 45 km/sec.

From a velocity standpoint, therefore, this weapon works.  From an energy standpoint, though, I doubt it's practical for anything less than a shipboard weapon and there's also the problem that much of that fusion energy comes off as gamma rays--the battlefield wouldn't be too healthy a place, especially on a rainy day.  (What happens when one of your shots hits a raindrop just after leaving the muzzle????)

Comment: Wouldn't a shot be colliding with the atoms in the air regardless of the weather?

Comment: @sphennings Of course.  It's just there's an awful lot more hydrogen in a water drop than in the air it would be passing through on the way to it's target, and the water drop is all in one place also.  The weapon would expend it's energy on the water drop, that would be a very bad thing for the shooter.